# Difference between these algorithm representations?

Tags: algorithm

Recently I've been studying algorithm analysis and in my class I've seen code like this to represent a sample algorithm:

```
z = 0
for x = 1; x <= n; x++ do
  for y = 1; y <= n; y++ do
    z = z + 1
  end for
end for
```

I understand that these for loops can be read as "as long as x/y is equal or lower than n do the following and at the end of each cycle add 1 to x/y, then test the condition again". However in some books like the algorithm design manual I see stuff like this:

```
r:= 0
for i:= 1 to n do
  for j:= 1 to i do
    for k:= j to i + j do
      r:= r + 1
return (r)
```

Is it esencially the same as the first example I gave or does it mean something different? It also conflicts me that in the second example there is no increments like `x++` so that the loop stops after a certain number of cycles. Also why stating `k:= j` instead of simply `k:= 1` since j=1 in this algorithm?

Clarification: I didn't mean to ask if they do the same in the sense of producing the same output, but rather refer to if the for loops in both of them work the same as in stopping after the value of n is matched when adding 1 after each cycle to for example the variable i (as it was done for x or y in the first example).

Comment: I haven't seen the `;=` symbol in pseudocode before. Is this an [assignment operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science))?

Comment: for the purpose of algorithm analysis which syntax you use for pseudo code is rather irrelevant. Each "standard loop" will have a O(n) complexity where n is the upper bound. The only real thing that could change the matter is if increment is multiplicative (eg. `i *= 2`) but other than that it doesn't matter.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I have no idea, this is another reason why I'm confused

Comment: @Jack yes I do understand the asymptotic notation part, however there is another analysis we can do of the algorithms in which we count the number of operations it executes to find an equation for its complexity. In the first example I can assign a value of 1 for the ´z=0´ , then values of 1 + n + 1 to the first loop (a variable assignment + n times the loop + 1 for the final condition check before exiting the loop) and so on and so forth. To do this kind of analysis I need to know what the code or pseudocode is actually doing and I do not understand what the second piece of code is doing.

Comment: I've seen `:=` (colon-equals) or `<-` used to denote assignment, to distinguish from `=` used as a statement of equality (as in mathematics).  I've never seen `;=` (semicolon-equals) before.  Are you sure you didn't misread it?

Comment: @pjs you are are right, dumb me. Edited the question

Comment: Given that, shouldn't the update to `r` now be `r := r + 1`?  Also, shouldn't that be indented another level?

Comment: Yes, its done. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I still suspect you need to add indentation.  Otherwise, by normal conventions your inner loop doesn't control anything.

Comment: yes... damn I messed that one up really bad lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your first algorithm is using a C-like notation where it specifies the starting state, the condition to proceed, and how the state gets updated after each iteration.

The second one appears to be using loops based on iterating over a specified range: "for each of the values in this range, do the following...".  This is fairly common in modern scripting languages such as Python or Ruby, and is arguably closer to how people think about iteration.

---

Either algorithm can be written using the other one's notation.

### Algorithm 1 / style 2

```
z := 0
for x := 1 to n do
  for y:= 1 to n do
    z := z + 1
return(z)       # I’m assuming you actually wanted a return value
```

### Algorithm 2 / style 1

```
r = 0
for i = 1; i <= n; i++ do
  for j = 1; j <= i; j++ do
    for k = j; k <= i + j; k++ do
      r = r + 1
    end for
  end for
end for
return(r)
```

Stick with one style or the other, and you'll see that the differences in the counts aren't because of the different pseudocode styles. These are different algorithms.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but I'm still confused about how the difference would affect the number of operations. We could say that in the first algorithm in the first for loop the start condition check is done n+1 times (the value of a given n as input + 1 more check at the end when the exit condition is met), the x variable assignment is done 1 time and the increment is also done n times since the variable x goes up by one in each cycle. The second algorithm would work the same but without the last n of variable updates since it doesn't need to check for i each cycle, would this be correct?

Comment: @MikeKatz45 That depends on whether your pseudocode is inclusive or exclusive on the range bounds.  I generally have seen inclusive, and people have either adjusted the range limit down to be exclusive, or (less commonly) stated explicitly in a comment that it's exclusive.  However, pseudocode doesn't have any defined standard, it's intended to communicate concepts without having to dot every i and cross every t as you have to do in formally defined languages.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is not really the same as the first one.
I read

```
for i;= 1 to n do
```

because of **1 to n** as

```
for i = 1; i <= n; i += 1
```

In each j-loop k is starting from j. So k is starting from 1 only in the first 
j-loop of each i-loop.

While the first algorithm is simply imaginable as rows and columns, the second one is not.

```js
function a1(n) {
  console.clear();
  console.log('algorithm 1');
  console.log('n = ' + n);
  console.log('x | y | z');
  var x, y, z = 0;
  var tr, td;
  
  for (x = 1; x <= n; x += 1) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (y = 1; y <= n; y++) {
      td = document.createElement('td');
      z = z + 1;
      console.log(x + ' | ' + y + ' | ' + z);
      tr.appendChild(td);
      td.innerHTML = z;
    }
    tbl1.appendChild(tr);
  }
}

function a2(n) {
var i, j, k, r = 0;
  console.clear();
  console.log('algorithm 2');
  console.log('n = ' + n);
  console.log('i | j | k |i+j| r')
for (i = 1; i <= n; i += 1) {
  for (j = 1; j <= i; j += 1) {
    for (k = j; k <= (i + j); k += 1) {
      r = r + 1;
      console.log(i+ ' | ' + j + ' | ' + k + ' | ' + (i+j) + ' | ' + r);
    }
  }
}
return (r);
}

// output table 1 handle
var tbl1 = document.getElementById('output1');

// Event handlers for buttons a1 and a2
document.getElementById("a1_start").addEventListener("click", function(){
  a1(5);
});
document.getElementById("a2_start").addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log('returns ' + a2(4));
});
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<button id="a1_start">
  start algorithm 1
</button>
 
<button id="a2_start">
  start algorithm 2
</button>
<table id="output1">
</table>
```

Comment: So you are saying that when they state `for i:= 1 to n` it is also implied that each cycle of the for loops will evaluate `i <= n` and perform `i++` at the end of each cycle?

Comment: Yes, that's what I think. I also think, it should not be `r := r + 1` but `r = r + 1` since I read `r := 0` as declare and define. But that's just guessing.